# React Native iOS TrueDepth Camera

Tags: react-native, avfoundation, react-native-ios, truedepth-camera

Is there a way to use and utilize [the native ios **truedepth** camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera?language=objc) (and get the visual depth) in **React Native** or any workaround or anything?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.